# Populate Xaml with an array in C#

Tags: c#, android, ios, xaml, xamarin

How can I populate Xaml with C# array (or list or dic) data like `ng-repeat` in angular. So given I have the following:

```
var list = new List<string>() { "item1", "item2" };
```

And a xaml view:

```
<StackLayout ng-repeat="x in list">
<SomeTag>TextHere</SomeTag>
<SomeOtherTag Text="x"></SomeOtherTag>
</StackLayout>
```

Assuming `SomeTag` and `SomeOtherTag` are valid tag names, how can I recreate `ng-repeat` behaviour in this. I am not looking for any dropdown boxes, I just want a looping mechanism

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're gonna need to use a `ListView` with an `ItemTemplate`. The ListView is the list itself, and then each item in your list of data will use the ItemTemplate to draw itself.

As i don't know if you're using Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Android or Xamarin.Forms, i can't give you a direct link to the documentation, but it should be easy to google.
I have personally created a listview as this in Xamarin.Forms, so i could potentially help more if you're also doing it with Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: I am using Xamarin Froms but didn't manage to get ListView working. for the time being I created my elements dinamically and added them as children which works as expected but isn't as nice and readable as Binding in Xaml